# Pulldown resistor on CLK input of 74HC109

Tags: clock, flipflop

I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of R3 on the CLK input of the 74109 in this circuit:

[image: Schematic of the circuit]

This is the [Clap activated light circuit](https://www.gadgetronicx.com/clap-activated-light-circuit/) by Frank Donald.

As far as I know, the 741 *should* be able to drive the CLK pin on its own. However, when testing this circuit in real life, using an LM741 and a 74HC109, the circuit behaves weirdly.

With the resistor it works properly, the Q pin being always low before the first clock pulse, but without it Q might start high or low, randomly.

I disconnected the 741 and measured the voltage across R3 to check if it leaked current, but it was 0 V.
I also checked the pin with an oscilloscope and a 555 timer to generate pulses. The waveform looks exactly the same with or without the resistor, no weird spikes or anything, but the 74109 still starts up on a random state.

I'm thinking that, maybe, it leaks some current briefly during startup, and that it is enough to trigger the flip-flop, but I couldn't see any spikes on the scope, so I'm not sure.

Comment: 741 is totally unsuitable in that position, what you're seeing is not reproducible from build to build, or even moment to moment.

Comment: good grief, that is actually a published circuit. That it works at all is surprising, it's certainly not reproducible. It relies on side effects and uncontrolled behaviour to work at all. 741 is not designed to work on 5 V. Pin 3 requires a bias current for proper operation, which C1 blocks, the voltage it ends up at is anybody's guess. Your question, the initial state of U2, is completely uncontrolled, as set and reset are tied high. Using resistors to tie them high, then a capacitor from one to ground would give you a defined state at power on.

Comment: @Neil_UK ah you are totally right, the datasheet doesn't specify any initial state. 
I guess that that resistor just "aligned the stars" to make Q be zero at the start. I've found an article from TI called [Power-up behaviour of clocked devices](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scha005b/scha005b.pdf) that talks about this issue and how to solve it, though I'd hope that the datasheet was a little more explicit about this.

Comment: The TTL datasheet is totally explicit about the power on state of such a latch, it's undefined, you get what you get. What will happen is that any given latch will tend to power on the same state, but there's no predicting what any latch will do until you try. Some logic devices do have a defined power on state, and if they do, they tell you about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing Mr. Donald knew that the 741's output was unable to get close enough to ground to register a "low" at the 74109 input, and had to resort to brute force, by pulling it down in potential with a resistor.

That's what R3 is doing, coercing the totally incompatible 741 output to be "recognisable" by a logic device input. It's bad, and it probably won't work anyway.

There are other problems with the use of a 741 here, not just its terrible output voltage range; it also can't handle *inputs* that get close to the supply potentials, without behaving badly. A 741 is practically useless with a power supply less than 8V or so, for these reasons.

The use of C1 in that position is a terrible design choice, too. Its purpose is clear, but its placement there without other resistors to "help" cannot possibly achieve predictable, required behaviour.

There's a lot that needs changing from the 741 leftwards. Don't spend any more time with this circuit, except to learn how *not* to do things.